# Send message to slack when a cell is set to a certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack-api

Hi I am trying to send message to slack from google sheets using app script. I have got it to work to post a message to Slack when a change is made to the column but I want to be able to send a message to slack when the status of a cell in that colum changes from Pending to In Progress. I have tried below but this does not seem to be working

```
function sendSlackMessage(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 4 || e.value ){
    var source = e.source;
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var emAddress = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
    var status = e.value;
    var url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/orgid/channelid";
    var payload = {
      text: "Hey <!here>, we have a request from " + emAddress + ". \n<@slackid>, can you please look into this"
    }

    var headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/jason'
    }
    var options = {
      headers: headers,
      method: "POST",
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have said `I have got it to work to post a message to Slack when a change is made to the column`  could you please provide details on how that was accomplished.

Comment: In your current implementation what it the source of the event object that populates the parameter `e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sendSlackMessage(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "In Progress") {
    var emAddress = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
    var url = "incoming webhookurl for the channel";
    var payload = {
      text: "Hey <!here>, we have a request from " + emAddress + ". \n<@slackuserid>, can you please look into this"
    }
    var headers = { 'Content-type': 'application/jason' }
    var options = { headers: headers, method: "POST", payload: JSON.stringify(payload) }
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  }
}
```

From the looks of this code I would guess that you have setup an installable onEdit trigger.  However, perhaps you do not realize that onEdit trigger only respond to user edits and not changes that originate from other scripts, custom functions or cell formulas.

Comment: `if (e.range.getColumn() == 4 || e.value == "In Progress" ){`

this does not work

but below sends message to slack
`if (e.range.getColumn() == 4 ){`

Comment: I think I missed the e.value == "In Progress " in my original question.

the trigger is set to onEdit as the rows are populated manually. changes are made in the sheet as such I used onEdit. 
Sorry I am not very proficient in app script ! thank you for your help !

Comment: Thanks so much for updating the code above. I realised that the operator was set to OR. Upon changing it to AND it posted message on slack whenever the status was changed to In Progress. `if (e.range.getColumn() == 4 && e.value == "In Progress" ){ `